# Updating variable table from #temp table - expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a `#temp` table with Order Details
e.g.

```
OrderID     CustomerID  DeliveredBy
1           10          12
2           13          14
3           15          14
```

I have a `@Orders`  table variable (which at this stage contains only specific order numbers - but no IDs fro Customers of DeliveryDetails)  with Columns:

```
OrderID     CustomerName    DeliveredByName
1
2
3
```

(This is just an example of the situation)

I need to update the `@Orders` table with the `CustomerName,DeliveredByName` with the IDs that are in the `#temp` table

```
Update @Orders
set 
    CustomerName = c.Name,
    DeliveredByName = d.Name
from @Orders o1
         join #temp t                on o1.OrderID = t.OrderID
    left join Customers c on o1.CustomerID = c.CustomerID    
    left join DeliveryDetails d on o1.DeliveredByID = d.DeliveredByID
```

But get the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'update'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified an alias to the `@orders`, you have to use it in the update clause, otherwise remove that alias. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE o1   <-------- here use UPDATE o1 instead of UPDATE @orders
SET o1.CustomerName    = c.Name,
    o1.DeliveredByName = d.Name
FROM @Orders AS o1
INNER JOIN #temp          AS t ON o1.OrderID       = t.OrderID
LEFT JOIN Customers       AS c ON o1.CustomerID    = c.CustomerID    
LEFT JOIN DeliveryDetails AS d ON o1.DeliveredByID = d.DeliveredByID;
```